# Differentiating class attributes

Tags: python, python-3.x

what would be the best way in Python to somehow "flag" some class attributes to be later able to distinguish them from the rest of "ordinary" class attributes?

possible use case: a class with such "marked" attributes is dynamically retrieved, you want to present user with only these attributes and for example let him modify them, ignoring the rest

i can think of this in a parallel to the way decorators work: you have a function and you decorate it with some additional functionality - similarly you have a property and i'd like to decorate that property with some additional property

Comment: What do you want to do that the `@property` decorator does not already do, assuming you know of / decided against it?

Comment: can you develop on the use of `@propery` ? the property getter could theoretically get me this "flag" information, but how do you instruct the getter to get you this and not the actual value? not to mention this approach seems completely twisted

Comment: [Here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/property) you can find the @property documentation.

Comment: I'm not 100% clear what you're trying to do, just pointing out that @property decorator would give you some flexibility. My only other suggestion would be to "mark" them by putting an underscore in front of the name of attributes you want to ignore, making them "private," but that might not be exactly what you want either.